# Selenium WebDriver Handling Windows Server Authentication using powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium Webdriver based test using powershell and chrome,
The windows server, is returning an authentication pop up window.

This is my current script:

```
$CDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver

$CDriver.Navigate().GoToURL('http://mytestserver/login/')

$CDriver.Navigate().GoToURL('http://admin:adm!n@mytestserver/login/')
```

I understand, that i will not be able to use elements, as this isn't a message from the website itself.

But i'm trying to understand if i can use the Alert mechanism in Selenium Webdriver,
Instead of passing the username and password, into the actual url?

This what i tried so far, but with no successes:

```
$alert = $CDriver.SwitchTo().Alert()
$alert.SendKeys("admin");
$alert.SendKeys("adm!n");
$alert.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

Also,
Is there is any official documentation for Selenium WebDriver and powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Many websites would rediret to a authentication site while accepting the credentials.
This renders $CDriver.Navigate().GoToURL('http://admin:adm!n@mytestserver/login/') useless.
An option which worked for me was as follows:
[Ofcourse this is in java, but i hope you figure it out]

`//url=orignal url of your application.

driver.get(url);

authURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();

driver.get("http://admin:adm!n@"+authURL.replaceFirst("https://","");`

Hope that works or please let me know in case of any questions.